# ResourceDictionary is not used as button style

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to use ResourceDictionary to set up a style for a button

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <vieModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="ButtonStyle"> //If I don't use key it gives error
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
     </Window.Resources>
```

and using it as

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

Now, when I do this it complains that ResourceDictionary can not be applied to Style. When I use "GlassButton" as defined in GlassButton.xaml it says that GlassButton could not be resolved.

when I use it like

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

or use GlassButton in both cases either it complains or wont work.

GlassButton.xaml looks like this, and compiling fine

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Citations">

<Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
```

I am taking this example from [here](http://www.jadeskaggs.com/2009/05/04/creating-custom-glass-buttons-with-xaml-in-wpf/) or [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32257/A-Style-for-Round-Glassy-WPF-Buttons) both are kind of using same approach of using ResourceDictionary. I am doing as shown but it still not working. Do I need a converter for this? or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me. Check that the path to GlassButton.xaml is correct. If you put it in a folder such as Styles you would need to use `Source="Styles/GlassButton.xaml"`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource GlassButton}"
            Content="Button Content"/>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Strange, it is not even asking you for key in , <ResourceDictionary x:Key="SomeButton">. Without it, it is giving me invalid markup. Do I need to add Data context in MainWindow.xaml.cs? As I already added  DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(); there

Comment: If you set your DataContext in the code behind you don't need to add it as a window resource.

Comment: It works when I remove <vieModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/> but then binding to other control stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I should be using it as follows

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vieModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

This worked

Answer (score 0):

Move the

> <vieModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>

line to inside of `ResoruceDictonary` like below:. Then you don't need to enter the key `x:Key="ButtonStyle"` and then style will be applied

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary > 
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="GlassButton.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <vieModel:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
 </Window.Resources>
```